# How can I create a new column that only extracts either the year or month from a mm/dd/yy hh:mm string?

Tags: r

I have a date/time string variable that looks like this:

```
> dput(df$starttime)
c("12/16/20 7:24", "6/21/21 13:20", "1/22/20 9:03", "1/07/20 17:19", 
"11/8/21 10:14", NA, NA, "10/26/21 7:19", "3/14/22 9:48", "5/12/22 13:29"
```

I basically want to create a column that only has the year (2020, 2021, 2022) and the year + month (e.g., "Jan 2022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Base R** Assuming that you want separate month and year numeric columns, define a function which converts a string in the format shown in the question to a year or month number and then invoke it twice.  No packages are used.

```
toNum <- function(x, fmt) format(as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%y"), fmt) |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
transform(df, year = toNum(starttime, "%Y"), month = toNum(starttime, "%m"))
```

giving

```
       starttime year month
1  12/16/20 7:24 2020    12
2  6/21/21 13:20 2021     6
3   1/22/20 9:03 2020     1
4  1/07/20 17:19 2020     1
5  11/8/21 10:14 2021    11
6           <NA>   NA    NA
7           <NA>   NA    NA
8  10/26/21 7:19 2021    10
9   3/14/22 9:48 2022     3
10 5/12/22 13:29 2022     5
```

**2) yearmon**  Assuming that you want a yearmon class column which represents year and month internally as year + fraction where fraction  is 0 for Ja, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec so that it sorts appropriately and adding 1/12, say, will give the next month we can use the following.  Note that if ym is yearmon then as.integer(ym) is the year and cycle(ym) is the month number (1, 2, ..., 12).

```
library(zoo)
transform(df, yearmon = as.yearmon(starttime, "%m/%d/%y"))
```

giving:

```
       starttime  yearmon
1  12/16/20 7:24 Dec 2020
2  6/21/21 13:20 Jun 2021
3   1/22/20 9:03 Jan 2020
4  1/07/20 17:19 Jan 2020
5  11/8/21 10:14 Nov 2021
6           <NA>     <NA>
7           <NA>     <NA>
8  10/26/21 7:19 Oct 2021
9   3/14/22 9:48 Mar 2022
10 5/12/22 13:29 May 2022
```

### Note

If you want to sort by `starttime` then use

```
ct <- as.POSIXct(df$starttime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df[order(ct),, drop = FALSE ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to convert to datetime class `POSIXct` with `mdy_hm` (from `lubridate`), then `format` to extract the month (`%b`) and 4 digit year (`%Y`), `filter` out the NA elements and `arrange` based on the converted datetime column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
   mutate(starttime = mdy_hm(starttime),
         yearmonth = format(starttime, "%b %Y")) %>%
   filter(complete.cases(yearmonth)) %>%
   arrange(starttime)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  starttime           yearmonth
  <dttm>              <chr>    
1 2020-01-07 17:19:00 Jan 2020 
2 2020-01-22 09:03:00 Jan 2020 
3 2020-12-16 07:24:00 Dec 2020 
4 2021-06-21 13:20:00 Jun 2021 
5 2021-10-26 07:19:00 Oct 2021 
6 2021-11-08 10:14:00 Nov 2021 
7 2022-03-14 09:48:00 Mar 2022 
8 2022-05-12 13:29:00 May 2022
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way I can sort this in chronological order too?

Comment: @Nat perhaps the update helps you

Answer (score 1):

If you want a chronologically sortable output, you could use the `tsibble::yearmonth` type:

```
tsibble::yearmonth(lubridate::mdy_hm(c("12/16/20 7:24", "6/21/21 13:20", "1/22/20 9:03", "1/07/20 17:19", 
  "11/8/21 10:14", NA, NA, "10/26/21 7:19", "3/14/22 9:48", "5/12/22 13:29")))
```

result

```
<yearmonth[10]>
 [1] "2020 Dec" "2021 Jun" "2020 Jan" "2020 Jan" "2021 Nov" NA         NA        
 [8] "2021 Oct" "2022 Mar" "2022 May"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

data.frame(df, 
  Year = format(mdy_hm(df$starttime), "%Y"), 
  MonthYear = format(mdy_hm(df$starttime), "%b %Y"))
       starttime Year MonthYear
1  12/16/20 7:24 2020  Dec 2020
2  6/21/21 13:20 2021  Jun 2021
3   1/22/20 9:03 2020  Jan 2020
4  1/07/20 17:19 2020  Jan 2020
5  11/8/21 10:14 2021  Nov 2021
6           <NA> <NA>      <NA>
7           <NA> <NA>      <NA>
8  10/26/21 7:19 2021  Oct 2021
9   3/14/22 9:48 2022  Mar 2022
10 5/12/22 13:29 2022  May 2022
```

It uses `mdy_hm` in conjunction with `format` to get the desired Year `%Y` and `%b %Y` abbreviated month and year part of the date.

Ordered rows:

```
df_new <- data.frame(df, 
  Year = format(mdy_hm(df$starttime), "%Y"), 
  MonthYear = format(mdy_hm(df$starttime), "%b %Y"))

df_new[order(my(df_new$MonthYear)),]
       starttime Year MonthYear
3   1/22/20 9:03 2020  Jan 2020
4  1/07/20 17:19 2020  Jan 2020
1  12/16/20 7:24 2020  Dec 2020
2  6/21/21 13:20 2021  Jun 2021
8  10/26/21 7:19 2021  Oct 2021
5  11/8/21 10:14 2021  Nov 2021
9   3/14/22 9:48 2022  Mar 2022
10 5/12/22 13:29 2022  May 2022
6           <NA> <NA>      <NA>
7           <NA> <NA>      <NA>
```

Without `NA`s

```
na.omit(df_new[order(my(df_new$MonthYear)),])
       starttime Year MonthYear
3   1/22/20 9:03 2020  Jan 2020
4  1/07/20 17:19 2020  Jan 2020
1  12/16/20 7:24 2020  Dec 2020
2  6/21/21 13:20 2021  Jun 2021
8  10/26/21 7:19 2021  Oct 2021
5  11/8/21 10:14 2021  Nov 2021
9   3/14/22 9:48 2022  Mar 2022
10 5/12/22 13:29 2022  May 2022
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(starttime = c("12/16/20 7:24", "6/21/21 13:20",
"1/22/20 9:03", "1/07/20 17:19", "11/8/21 10:14", NA, NA, "10/26/21 7:19",
"3/14/22 9:48", "5/12/22 13:29")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-10L))
```

Comment: @akrun I am still writing, haven't checked any other answer

Comment: @akrun not using dplyr, including year. But if you feel it's a duplicated answer I can delete mine.

Comment: You are right.  I was only checking the lubridate part.  You can keep it